Newtonian “zero net pull force” at center of star/planet vs. GR singularity of black hole

At the center of a black hole, tidal forces become extremely large (classically infinite at the singularity).

But in a Newtonian model, the net pull at the center of a spherically symmetric mass distribution is zero, cf. e.g. this and this Phys.SE posts.


How do I reconcile these statements?”

As you get closer the gravitational force does NOT get weaker...

Why should it get weaker if the whole mass is at r=0? You have 2 horizons in Kerr, but you seem to be talking about Schwarzschild, and there you haven't.

A black hole is not a ball of mass.

I would not have closed this question. It is completely clear what OP is asking, and it is based on a uniform spherical mass that smaller than its Schwarzschild radius. Since the Newtonian computation of $v_{escape} = c$ reproduces the the horizon radius, it kind of makes sense. If you think the horizon is about local "g", then there are 2 radii where that happens, if it's based on potential energy, then: no. (note: there is no "horizon" w/ Newton). So a decent answer could explain all that, but OP isn't getting answer because y'all closed it.

What does "exit the center of mass" mean? As @Ghoster said, a black hole is not a ball of mass. The two are different things; there is no contradiction; can you clarify what is there to reconcile?

If you are 1mm from the center of the Earth, then 1/2 of the Earth's mass is "above" you, canceling the pull in the opposite direction from the other half. When you are 1mm from the singularity of a black hole, then there is nothing "above" you. The entire mass is at the singularity.

@SolomonSlow you should post this as an answer.

@Yukterez All mass of a real black hole is at the horizon, which is at $r=0$ where $r$ is defined per Schwarzschild as the spacelike radial distance. The “inner” spacetime, including the singularity, is the future evolution that hasn’t happened yet and thus has no mass. In the eternal black hole, all mass also is at the horizon, as otherwise it would be undetectable outside and therefore producing zero gravity.

@safesphere wrote: "all mass also is at the horizon" - The Kretschmann scalar tells a different story.

@Yukterez It doesn’t. This scalar has nothing to do with the location of mass. Note that the mass of a black hole has a zero stress energy tensor and thus doesn’t directly affect the curvature measured by this scalar. You keep forgetting that singularity is in the future and thus cannot be a source of anything now, but is a result of the curvature, not its case.

@safesphere - The question was about the tidal forces at the center, which are only felt by someone who already fell into the black hole, so the time dilation in the frame of an external observer doesn't help your argument. If all the mass was in an infinitely thin shell at the horizon it would require infinite density, which would lead to an infinite Kretschmann scalar.

@Yukterez Right. In this case all the mass is in the Schwarzschild inner timeslice $r=R$ where $R$ is the coordinate time of the falling observer. Loosely speaking, this slice is a rapidly shrinking thin spherical (spherinder) shell containing the observer. Still zero mass in the singularity that doesn’t exist yet on the clock of this observer. In his view though this slice isn’t thin, but this has no effect on the singularity still not existing and having no mass. Your density point doesn’t hold since all energy of the matter there is kinetic with a zero stress energy tensor.

@safesphere - even if the energy was only kinetic (which it ain't since that is only the case for lightlike worldlines) that would not lead to a zero energy tensor, in the FLRW we have radiation dominated universes with nonzero Tμν but we're talking about the Kretschmann scalar anyway. The Tμν is only zero in Schwarzschild cause the r=0 is excluded from the manifold an we have a Delta function there. In the Oppenheimer Snyder frame where the star collapses the density if nonzero and gets infinite at the center in finite proper time.

@Yukterez All your objections are moot and can’t be debated in comments. The free falling worldline is lightlike at the horizon. Sure a timelike geodesic cannot become lightlike, but it either  does or it ends at the horizon. FLRW is a failed model not worth  mentioning. The OS collapse is based on FLRW and thus the same. And there is no delta at $r=0$ for many reasons. The main one is that energy and time are Fourier conjugates - when time ends, energy disappears. Another reason of many is that it doesn’t matter what happens to matter at the last moment of its existence, it causes no results.

@Yukterez If you drive a car to a wall and crash, where is the mass of the car? Is it at the wall? Or is it in the garage? Obviously it is where the car is at the moment. So evidently in a real collapse the mass of the star is in the timeslice. We see it at the horizon forever. “Then” it moves in time along $r$. It does get asymptotically to the singularity, but only when no other place exists anymore. So saying that mass is at the singularity while anything still exists anywhere else is absurd. The mass of your car is at the wall only after you crash, not while you are still in the garage.
